Set the Focus of Field on Page Load
I have created a Lightning Web Component page to display various fields on a Task. I am trying to set the focus to the first field on the page when the page is loaded. I was able to use the renderedCallback and a flag to set the focus. But, the next time you go to the page, the logic to set focus does not work.
I have tried resetting the flag in the connectedCallback, but that is not working for me either. It will also only reset that variable one time and then the next time you go to the page it just skips it.
Is there a better way to handle setting the focus to an input field? Or should I be resetting the flag differently?
Here is the logic I have for the renderedCallback:
    renderedCallback() {
        // Bring focus to the Subject when the page loads
        if (this.bringFocusOnPageLoad) {
            const noteSubject = this.template.querySelector('[id^="subject"]');

            if (noteSubject) {
                noteSubject.focus();
                this.bringFocusOnPageLoad = false;
            }
        }
    }

Here is my the input field I am trying to set the focus to:
                <lightning-input id="subject"
                                 type="text"
                                 label="Subject"
                                 variant="label-inline"
                                 value="Note"
                                 onchange={checkNoteReqFields}
                                 autofocus="true"
                                 required
                ></lightning-input>


You can directly set the focus in the renderedCallback and ensure it runs every time the component is rendered.
Remove the flag and set the focus directly in the renderedCallback. Also, Use a slight delay to ensure the element is available in the DOM before setting the focus.
JS::
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TaskComponent extends LightningElement {
        renderedCallback() {
                const noteSubject = this.template.querySelector('[id^="subject"]');

                if (noteSubject) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                                noteSubject.focus();
                        }, 0);
                }
        }
}

HTML::
<template>
        <lightning-input id="subject"
                        type="text"
                        label="Subject"
                        variant="label-inline"
                        value="Note"
                        onchange={checkNoteReqFields}
                        required>
        </lightning-input>
</template>

As using setTimeout, It's ensure that the focus is set after the DOM is fully rendered.

Why would the element not be in the DOM after render?

I can confirm, simply getting a handle to the field in the renderdCallback and calling focus() will not work.  But wrapping it in setTimeout() does the trick.  Thank you!
